# Accessing to imageUrls (which contains an array of urls in firebase storage) in my collection doc shows me undefined

Tags: reactjs, typescript, firebase

I am new to React (with TypeScript) and Firebase. My code uploads multiple images to firebase storage and sends URLs of those images to my collection document. I read the data from collection. But when I try to console.log the imageUrls field, it shows undefined. However the array of urls is in imageUrls field. So when I console.log the whole collection, I can see imageUrls data. Anyone has an idea what is going on? Thank you!

I tried to paste manually urls in that array. It worked. So the problem is in rendering imageUrls fields, because I still get the data from other fields from that exact document. Iterface of types for fetching data seems to be correct.

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ('**why isn't this code working?**') must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)" and [Build a minimal, complete, reproducible example](https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/minimal-complete-reproducible-example)